# How to fix React Context's object is not a function - TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-typescript

I am trying to solve this error for a few days now, I'm trying to pass context to my components, whatever I try, I get the error "The object is not a function" or "The object is not iterable"

I was trying to do this with Typescript, and I thought it might be something else, so I tried using react javascript cli and here are the errors below with my code pictures.

[image: Error]

[image: Wrapper]

[image: Context]

[image: Component]

Answer (score 4):

The value of the context is `{state,setState}` not `[state,setState]`

Just do this:

```js
console.log(useContext(GlobalContext))
```

and you will see that the context is an object with two properties - `state` and `setState` as given by this line:

```js
<GlobalContext.Provider value={{state,setState}}>
```

Also, post code, don't post pictures of code.

Comment: I really love you man! It is solved!!!!!!!!!! Thank you, will do thanks on advices.